# Based on the 2 column data, need to look up and data to another sheet horizontally

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 column's data in a sheet 1. Column 2 might have a value which might have multiple corresponding values in column 1

Now in sheet 2, I have the list of Column 2 values and for each value, I need to look up the corresponding Column 1 values horizontally in sheet 2.

Could you please help?

I have attached a screenshot for your reference

[image]

Comment: Try: `TOROW()` & `FILTER()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `FILTER()` with `TOROW()` or `TRANSPOSE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=TOROW(FILTER($A$2:$A$6,G2=$B$2:$B$6,""))
```

---

You can also spill the formula using `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",G2:G7,LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,TOROW(FILTER(A2:A6,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B6,y)),""))))),""),1)
```

---

Or, if you are not using `MS365` then use the below

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        $A$2:$A$6,
        AGGREGATE(
            15,
            7,
            (
                ROW(
                    $A$2:$A$6
                ) - 1
            ) /
                (
                    $G2 =
                        $B$2:$B$6
                ),
            COLUMN(A1)
        )
    ),
    ""
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mayukh, Transpose and Filter worked. You are Amazing.