# Indirect formula in excel does not work, but when pasting the same string in its own cell, it does

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data. One column contains parent-type data; the other contains children-type data of a certain attribute.

e.g. (Not actual data)

Sheet AllData

[image: AllData]

The data is to be turned into a list of just parents in Column A, and Columns B thru END will have the Children listed out (as many or as little as they may be).

e.g.

Sheet Final List

[image: FinalList]

The way I planned to go about it was to use MATCH and INDEX to find a value (could have easily used XLOOKUP as well), and I would use INDIRECT(CONCAT(#####)) to not get the same value every time.

e.g.

'For the above columns

The formula in Cell B2 would be, `INDEX('AllData'!$B$2:$B$100, H2)`
The formula in Cell H2 would be, `MATCH(A2,'AllData'!$A$2:$A$100,0)`

The formula in Cell B3 would be, `INDEX('AllData'!$B$2:$B$100, H3)`
The formula in Cell H3 would be, `IFERROR( INDIRECT( CONCAT( "MATCH(A",ROW(A2), ",'AllData'!$B$", H2 + 2, "$B$100,0)") ) , 0) + H2`

When executing the formula, the IFERROR statement took over. But when isolating to just the INDIRECT statement, I got a `#REF` error. However, when using just CONCAT copying the String, Pasting As Values in another cell, and putting a "=" in-front, the formula executes correctly.

I have attempted numerous ways around this.

- Opening another sheet and trying it in a new Excel Document.
- Using the Char() codes for apostrophes and commas.
- Writing out both sheet names in the string as opposed to just the non-selected one.
- Writing out the string in its entirety.
- Etc. Etc.

Comment: Use TRANSPOSE and FILTER then copy that formula down.  No need for all the gymnastics:  `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=A2))`

Comment: You can refer here as well: **[TRANSPOSE() FILTER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227653/based-on-the-2-column-data-need-to-look-up-and-data-to-another-sheet-horizontal)**

Comment: Don't use `INDIRECT()` function it is `Single-threaded` will make excel work slower. Instead use the one as suggested by @ScottCraner Sir or check out the link i have posted.

Comment: @ScottCraner , yours worked! Thanks! Any thoughts as to why indirect wouldnt work in this case though? Just out of curiosity.